# VB.NET row count can't see more than 1 HtmlTableRow, dynamically added using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I'm having an issue counting rows and showing data from an HTML Table in ASP.NET using VB.NET code behind. I have created a html table that dynamically create a new row using jQuery.

I am trying to get the values from each of the html inputs. The input values show fine (see below), but when I try to pull more than a single row - they do not show.

Here is my VB.NET Code for looping the values:

```
 For Each row As HtmlTableRow In POITable.Rows

            'Get Row ID's except for Header Row.
            If Not POITable.Controls.IndexOf(row).ToString = "0" Then
                Debug.WriteLine("Row #:" + POITable.Controls.IndexOf(row).ToString)
            End If

            For Each cell As HtmlTableCell In row.Cells

                For Each ctrl As Control In cell.Controls
                    'CONTROL IS HIDDEN INPUT FIELD - SELECTIZE VALUE
                    If TypeOf ctrl Is HtmlInputHidden Then
                        Dim input As HtmlInputHidden = DirectCast(ctrl, HtmlInputHidden)
                        Debug.WriteLine("Project Code Found - id:" + input.ID + ", value:" + input.Value)
                    End If

                    'CONTROL IS INPUT
                    If TypeOf ctrl Is HtmlInputGenericControl Then
                        Dim input As HtmlInputGenericControl = DirectCast(ctrl, HtmlInputGenericControl)
                        Debug.WriteLine("Input Found - id:" + input.ID + ", sv:" + input.Value)
                    End If

                    If TypeOf ctrl Is HtmlInputText Then
                        Dim input As HtmlInputText = DirectCast(ctrl, HtmlInputText)
                        Debug.WriteLine("Comments found - id:" + input.ID + ", val:" + input.Value)
                    End If
                Next

            Next
  Next
```

However, the following result shows a single row - when in fact there are 2 (excluding the omitted header row):

```
    Row #:1
    Project Code Found - id:hf, value:20089
    Comments found - id:comments1, val: 
    Input Found - id:sat01, sv:0
    Input Found - id:sun01, sv:0
    Input Found - id:mon01, sv:0
    Input Found - id:tue01, sv:0
    Input Found - id:wed01, sv:0
    Input Found - id:thu01, sv:0
    Input Found - id:fri01, sv:0
    Input Found - id:total01, sv:0
```

Here is the code for my table:

```
<table id="POITable" runat="server" enableviewstate="true" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                 <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th class="col-xs-5">Project Code
        </th>
                      <th class="col-xs-3">Comments
        </th>
                      <th style="width: 20px;">SAT
        </th>
                      <th style="width: 20px;">SUN
        </th>
                      <th style="width: 20px;">MON
        </th>
                      <th style="width: 20px;">TUE
        </th>
                      <th style="width: 20px;">WED
        </th>
                      <th style="width: 20px;">THU
        </th>
                      <th style="width: 20px;">FRI
        </th>
                      <th style="width: 30px;">TOTAL
        </th>
                      <th class="col-xs-1">&nbsp
        </th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="tbody1">
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="projectcode1_dd" CssClass="dd" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="width: 100%;"></asp:DropDownList>
                          <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hf" class="hf" />

                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text" runat="server" id="comments1" class="form-control input-sm comments" style="text-align: center;" value="&nbsp;">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="number" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm txtCal" id="sat01" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="number" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm txtCal" id="sun01" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="number" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm txtCal" id="mon01" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="number" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm txtCal" id="tue01" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="number" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm txtCal" id="wed01" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="number" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm txtCal" id="thu01" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="number" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm txtCal" id="fri01" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="number" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm txtCal" id="total01" style="width: 60px; text-align: center;" disabled>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group">
                              <input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="+" onclick="insRow()" />
                              <input type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="-" />
                          </div>

                      </td>

                  </tr>

              </tbody>

          </table>
```

and finally the jQuery for the new row:

```
           $(document).ready(function () {

        $('input.currency').number(true, 2);


        var date = document.getElementById("#<%=weekending_tb.ClientID%>")
        date = new Date();
        var n = date.getDay();
        if (n == 5)
            console.log("Its weekend!!");
        else
            console.log("Its not weekend");


        var REGEX_EMAIL = '([a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@' +
         '(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)';


        $('.dd').change(function () {

            var selectedvalue = $(this).val();
            console.log("Selected Value: " + selectedvalue)

            var hiddenfield = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('.hf');
            console.log("Hidden Field: " + hiddenfield)

            $(this).parents('tr').find('.hf').val(selectedvalue);

            console.log("hiddenfield value post: " + $(this).parents('tr').find('.hf').val())


        })




        hourscheck2();
        registerEvents();

        function formatRepo(data) {
            if (data.loading) return data.text;

            var markup = '<div class="clearfix">' +
    '<div clas="col-xs-12">' +
    '<div class="clearfix">' +
    '<div class="col-xs-4">' + data.text + '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-xs-8">' + data.desc + '</div>' +
    '</div>';

            markup += '</div></div>';

            return markup;

        }




        function formatRepoSelection(data) {
            return data.text
        }

        $('input').each(function (index) {
            $(this).on('input', function () {
                hourscheck2();
            });
        });

        $('#sat').on('input', function () {
            hourscheck2();
        });
        $('#sun').on('input', function () {
            hourscheck2();
        });
        $('#mon').on('input', function () {
            hourscheck2();
        });
        $('#tue').on('input', function () {
            hourscheck2();
        });
        $('#wed').on('input', function () {
            hourscheck2();
        });
        $('#thu').on('input', function () {
            hourscheck2();
        });
        $('#fri').on('input', function () {
            hourscheck2();
        });

        $("#<%= POITable.ClientID %>").on('input', '.txtCal', function () {
            var calculated_total_sum = 0;

            $("#<%= POITable.ClientID %> .txtCal").each(function () {
                var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
                if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
                    calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
                }
            });
            $("#total").val(calculated_total_sum);
        });




        $('.delete').on('click', function (event) {

            console.log("deleterow clicked");
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            tr.remove();

        });




    });






    function registerEvents() {
        //Get all the select events from the page and register events only on those controls which are new ..
        if ($(this)[0].selectize) {

        } else {
            $("select").each(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("id")
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    var $select = $(this).selectize({

                        persist: false,
                        plugins: ['remove_button'],
                        maxItems: 1,
                        valueField: 'tkd_task_no',
                        labelField: 'tkh_job_code',
                        placeholder: "Type your Task Name/Number",
                        searchField: ['tkh_job_code', 'tkh_job_number', 'tkh_desc50', 'tkd_task_no', 'tkd_desc50'],
                        onChange: function (value) {

                            var hiddenfield = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('.hf').val(value);

                        },
                        options: [],
                        render: {
                            item: function (item, escape) {
                                return '<div>' +
                                             (item.tkh_job_number ? '<span class="jobnumber" style="font-weight:bold; ">' + escape(item.tkh_job_code) + '</span> - ' : '') +
                                             (item.tkd_task_no ? '<span class="tasknumber" style="font-weight:bold; ">' + escape(item.tkd_task_no) + '</span> | ' : '') +
                                             (item.tkh_desc50 ? '<span class="jobdescription">' + escape(item.tkh_desc50) + '</span> - ' : '') +
                                             (item.tkd_desc50 ? '<span class="taskdescription" style="font-weight:bold;"s>' + escape(item.tkd_desc50) + '</span>' : '') +
                                         '</div>';



                                ;

                            },
                            option: function (item, escape) {
                                var label = item.tkh_job_code;
                                var caption = item.tkh_job_code ? item.tkh_desc50 : null;
                                return '<div>' +
                                              '<span class="jobnumber" style="font-weight:bold;">' + escape(label) + '</span> - ' +
                                    '<span class="tasknumber" style="font-weight:bold; ">' + escape(item.tkd_task_no) + '</span> | ' +
                                    '<span class="jobdescription">' + escape(item.tkh_desc50) + '</span> - ' +
                                             '<span class="taskdescription" style="font-weight:bold;">' + escape(item.tkd_desc50) + '</span>' +
                                          '</div>';
                            }
                        },

                        create: false,
                        selectOnTab: true,
                        load: function (query, callback) {
                            if (!query.length) return callback();
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/Timesheet/ProjectInfo.asmx/HelloJSON',
                                type: 'GET',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data: {
                                    searchField: query,
                                },
                                error: function () {
                                    callback();
                                },
                                success: function (res) {
                                    callback(res);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }




            });

            $('.delete').on('click', function (event) {

                console.log("deleterow clicked");
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                tr.remove();
                $(this).find('.txtCal:not(:last)').val = 0
                hourscheck2();

            });


        }






    }



    function hourscheck2() {
        var totalall = 0
        var overtime = 0
        var zero = 0
        var standardhours = $("#" + '<%= standardhours_hf.ClientID %>').val();

            $('tr').each(function () {
                var total = 0;
                $(this).find('.txtCal:not(:last)').each(function () {
                    total += (+$(this).val());
                    if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                        $(this).val(zero)
                    }
                });
                $(this).find('.txtCal:last').val(total);
                totalall += total

            });

            $("#<%= totalCal1.ClientID %>").val(totalall)

            if (totalall >= standardhours) {
                overtime = totalall - standardhours
            }

            $("#<%= standardhoursCal1.ClientID %>").val(standardhours)
            $("#<%= overtimeCal1.ClientID %>").val(overtime)
        }

        var value123;

        function deleteRow(row) {
            var i = row.parent.rowIndex;
        }




        function insRow() {

            // Find last row in table (or div) to clone from
            var lastRow = $("#<%= POITable.ClientID %>").find('tr').last();

            // Determine if selectize.js is in use on any element and disable
            // before cloning.
            var selectizeElements = {};
            lastRow.find('select').each(function () {

            });

            // Clone last row
            newRow = lastRow.clone().insertAfter(lastRow);
            newRow.find('select').each(function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });


            newRow.find('div').each(function () {

                if ($(this).hasClass('selectize-control')) {


                    $(this).remove();

                    $("#<%= POITable.ClientID %> > tbody > tr:eq(" + $(this).index() + ") > td:nth-child(1)").append("<select id=projectcode" + $(this).parent('#<%= POITable.ClientID %>').index() + 1 + "_dd style=&quot;width: 100%;&quot;></select>")

                }

                newRow.find('hiddenfield').each(function () {

                    var $hf = $(this);

                    newRow.find('.dd').change(function () {
                        var x = $(this).val();
                        $hf.val(x);
                    });

                });

            });

            // Clear any data that was already entered in the cloned row
            newRow.find('input,textarea,button').each(function () {
                if (!$(this).hasClass('btn')) {
                    $(this).val('');
                }
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
            });

            //Re-enable any selectize.js fields if needed, adding back
            //any options and selected values to the original row.
            if (!$.isEmptyObject(selectizeElements)) {
                $.each(selectizeElements, function (key, value) {
                }),

                //Copy back options and values to cloned row
                $.each(selectizeElements, function (key, value) {
                    lastRow.find('select#' + key)[0].selectize.addOption(value.inputOptions);
                    lastRow.find('select#' + key)[0].selectize.setValue(value.inputValue);

                })
            }

            // I usually update the id and name attribute index number here so
            // that each form element has a unique id and name.

            newRow.find('input,select,textarea,button').each(function () {
                var x1 = document.getElementById('<%= POITable.ClientID %>');
                var len = x1.rows.length;
                var id = $(this).attr("id")
                $(this).attr("id", id + len++)
            });

            $('input').each(function (index) {
                $(this).on('input', function () {
                    hourscheck2();
                });
            });



            registerEvents();
            hourscheck2();

        }

        function success() {

            var id = ""
            var hv = $("#" + '<%= timesheetid.ClientID %>').val();

            swal({
                title: "Timesheet Submitted Successfully",
                type: "success",
                html: "<p>Your Timesheet will now go to your line manager for approval. Would you like to submit expenses?<p><br/><a href='/Expenses/Add?timesheetid=" + hv + "' class='btn btn-success'>Add Expenses</a>&nbsp<a href='/Dashboard' class='btn btn-default'>Return to Dashboard</a>",
                showCloseButton: false,
                showCancelButton: false,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                allowOutsideClick: false,

            })

        }
```

Many thanks in advance guys!

Chris

Comment: I am not understand that you created html table from dbtable or from html to code side you need ? also you written " dynamically create a new row using jQuery", but there is no jquery in your question? please elaborate more with data to clear understand

Comment: If you add rows with jQuery, they will not be available in code behind after a PostBack. If you want to add rows you have to use ajax or something similar to communicate back and forth from the server.

Comment: Sorry @Ajay2707, I have added the jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @VDWWD - I will try and work out the approach for that.